# How to initialize retainedFileCountLimit indefinitely from config

Tags: c#, logging, serilog, rollingfilesink

Trying to convert the following code configuration into a config line:

```
.WriteTo.RollingFile(@"C:\Foo\Bar-{Date}.txt", retainedFileCountLimit: null)
```

The documentation for the rolling file sink states that in order to retain the logs indefinitely one must send the `retainedFileCountLimit` parameter as `null`.

I tried this

```
<add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.pathFormat" value="C:\Foo\Bar-{Date}.txt" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.retainedFileCountLimit" value="null" />
```

but as I expected the `null` literal is not accepted, moreover it seems like a direct conversion to Int32 is attempted.

Here is the stack trace for reference:

```
[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +14345541
   System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +305
   System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider) +859
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +248
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +536
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +80
   Serilog.Extras.AppSettings.PrefixedAppSettingsReader.ConfigureLogger(LoggerConfiguration loggerConfiguration) +1983
   Serilog.LoggerConfigurationAppSettingsExtensions.ReadAppSettings(LoggerConfiguration loggerConfiguration) +16
```

Comment: Looks like a bug/limitation in the `AppSettings` support. I'll add a ticket on Serilog's GitHub site for it - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the code at [Serilog.FullNetFx](http://dotnetinside.com/in/type/Serilog.FullNetFx/RollingFileSink/1.3.0.0) I'd guess you shouldn't add the value attribute at all.

Comment: No, the default value is 31 if not initialized.

Comment: The bug is now fixed (1.3.30), so @Primc's suggestion of `<add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.retainedFileCountLimit"/>` (just leave the value out) is now correct :)

Comment: Updated nuget packages and confirmed it no longer throws an error. Thanks for the speedy turnaround.